# Creating Microsoft Flow Custom Connector fails with "Failed to upload file"

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to create a Microsoft Flow Custom Connector, from an OpenAPI file, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/custom-connectors/define-openapi-definition).

It allows me to import the file, and correctly shows the actions in the UI. However when I come to click "Create Connector", it fails with the message "Failed to upload file XXX with size 7952 and sasUrl https://...".

When I look in the browser network log, I see it is making OPTIONS requests to:
https://pafeblobprodln.blob.core.windows.net/20180510t000000z97e13b316929479b8f4f2ae6ab7856ba/sage-200-flow-connectorswagger.json?sv=2017-04-17&sr=c&si=SASpolicy&sig=XXX=&comp=block&blockid=XXX=

Which are failing with "403 CORS not enabled or no matching rule found for this request". The request 'Origin' header is set to https://unitedkingdom.flow.microsoft.com

It looks like CORS isn't enabled on the blob container, at least for unitedkingdom.flow.microsoft.com.

Using the same OpenAPI file, I can successfully create a *Logic Apps* Custom Connector, just not a *Flow* Custom Connector.

Has anyone else encountered, and worked around this problem?

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 1):

I found same problem. I did manage to make it work by creating the custom connector in powerapps via web.powerapps.com instead and then could use it in Flow. Hope that helps.

I also found that can't create approvals connectors in UK Flow. At least in the default environment you can't. If you make a new environment they can work.